# transactions not picking the date of the good reception

Tags: python, date, odoo

I tried to make a good reception whose transactions get its date,but the good reception holds the date and when i click on all transactions the list view shows all the other info but the date is blank;any help plz

```
class goods_reception(models.Model):
        _name = "rcs.goods_reception"


        name = fields.Char(compute='compute_name')
        reference = fields.Char(string="Reference Document")
        warehouse = fields.Many2one("stock.warehouse", string="Prison", readonly="1")
        supplier = fields.Many2one("res.partner", string="Supplier", required=True)
        received_goods = fields.One2many("rcs.stock_transaction", "reception")
        received_by  = fields.Many2one("res.users", readonly=True)
        date = fields.Date(required=True)
        state = fields.Selection([
         ('pending', "Pending"),
         ('received', "Received"),
        ], default='pending', readonly=True)


        @api.one
        def compute_name(self):
#check
                self.name = "Reception No:"+str(self.id)+", Supplier:"+self.supplier.name+", Date:"+self.date

        @api.model
        def create(self, vals):
                vals['received_by'] = self.env.user.id
                vals['warehouse'] = self.env.user.warehouse.id
                return super(goods_reception, self).create(vals)

        @api.one
        def action_pending(self):
                self.state = 'pending'
```

Comment: When you try to save a goods reception, doesn't it asking you to set the date? as it is a mandatory field.

Comment: found it i replaced the date by the create date and it worked